# How to forward sessionExpired.jsp in Spring MVC globaly, when session expired

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new in spring MVC.I don't know how to  forward sessionExpired.jsp in Spring MVC globaly, when session expired.
I googled a lot but I didn't get any solution.What ever I am getting they are using spring security.In our application we are not using Spring security.

Please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this code it should solve your issue

```
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="SessionExpired.jsp" session-authentication-error-url="AlreadyLoggedIn.jsp">
<security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="SessionIsDuplicated.jsp" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
</security:session-management>
```

**Without using security, there are two ways in Spring MVC you can use HandlerInterceptorAdapter or Filters in Servlets.**

*Using HandlerInterceptorAdapter*

In springContext.xml

```
<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="com.nalashaa.interceptor.SessionValidatorInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>

package com.nalashaa.interceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

@Component
public class SessionValidatorInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
if (request.getServletPath().equals("/login.htm")) {  //for Login Page
        return true;
    }
if(request.getSession().getAttribute("userName")!=null){
return true;
}else{
response.sendRedirect("login.htm");
return false;
} 
}
}
```

*Using Filter*

In web.xml

```
<filter>  
<filter-name>SessionValidatorFilter</filter-name>  
 <filter-class>com.nalashaa.filter.SessionValidatorFilteFilter</filter-class>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
 <filter-name>SessionValidatorFilter</filter-name>  
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>   

package com.nalashaa.filter;  

import java.io.IOException;  
import javax.servlet.Filter;  
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;  
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;  

public class SessionValidatorFilter implements Filter {  

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {  
// initialization 
} 


public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  
 if(((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestedSessionId() != null && ((HttpServletRequest)request).isRequestedSessionIdValid() == false) {  
  RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp");  
  requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);  
 }else {  
  chain.doFilter(request, response);  
 }  
}  

public void destroy() {  
//Destroy code
}  

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I am not using Spring security.I think what ever you posted that is implementing security.

Comment: Edited the answer above

Comment: Hey... Please accept the answer. This will close the question and will make it easier for folks to search for answers later on!